# how do I print the smallest and largest number of n random numbers without using lists or any other data structure

Tags: python

The program should read a positive integer n from the user to decide how many number to generate.
The random numbers should be in the intervall [1, 100].
I should then print the average value, smallest value and largest value.
But WITHOUT using lists or any other data structure.
I managed to get the average value but I still need to get smallest and largest. any advise?

[here is how my code look like so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFMgq.png)

Comment: As you go, keep track of the smallest and largest values you have seen so far.  If you ever see something smaller/larger than the current best values, update them.

Comment: Also, please post code as [text instead of as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3282436).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you are trying to print the smallest and largest number of these five numbers without using a list.

You can easily create variables, and change them, if a higher/lower value is generated, then the highest/lowest value before. Hope it helps:

```
import random

n = int(input("Enter a number of integers to be generated: "))

if n < 0:
    print("Please enter a positive integer!")
else:
    highest_value = 0
    smallest_value = 100
    sum_of_random = 0
    for x in range(n):
        x = random.randint(1, 100)
        sum_of_random += x
        if x > highest_value:
            highest_value = x
        if x < smallest_value:
            smallest_value = x
        print(x, end = " ")

    print("\n")
    avg = round(sum_of_random / n, 2)
    print(avg)

    print(highest_value)
    print(smallest_value)
```

If this answers your question, please mark it as a correct answer.

Comment: thanks for the answers guys, I solved it already before seeing your answers, but it's similar to what you have answered. here is my code  [link] (https://imgur.com/a/QBH3xhv)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in min() and max() functions. Here's a bit of code, should be pretty self explanatory:

```
import random

n = 20

# set up the values 
smallest = 101
biggest  = -1

for i in range(n):
    x = random.randint(1,100)
    
    # take the smallest of the new random number and the current smallest
    smallest = min(x, smallest)
    
    # take the biggest of the new random number and the current biggest
    biggest  = max(x, biggest)
    
print(smallest, biggest)
```

Comment: Sorry.  My mistake.  But I think this is a homework question, and I don't like giving complete answers to homework questions.

Comment: yeah, I already solved myself, I don't want solutions, I asked for advice